# How do i convert binary to decimal (LUA)

Tags: lua

I know that there's tonumber() function, but the problem is that i need to convert larger numbers like `1000100110100011111010101001001001001100100101` . I can write that by myself, but is there a way to integrate that in function? And if I write that in current function, it returns different number. For example: through wolfram alpha, I converted "Something" (base 36) to binary and got `10010011001100011001011110001100000110110101100`.
If I put that in my custom function and convert back to base 36, I get `1Z141Z3` or `4294967295` (range for unassigned int)

Comment: Lua 5.3 natively support integers up to 64bits long. So that should suffice for most needs. If you need arbitrarily long integers use https://github.com/LuaDist/lbc

Comment: The official home of lbc is http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lbc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua supports 64bit integers since 5.3. Is your Lua up to date?

Open http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo
and execute this quick and dirty conversion. The result matches your quoted Wolfram Alpha number.

```
local dec = 80920602611116

local bin = "10010011001100011001011110001100000110110101100"

bin = string.reverse(bin)
local sum = 0

for i = 1, string.len(bin) do
  num = string.sub(bin, i,i) == "1" and 1 or 0
sum = sum + num * math.pow(2, i-1)

end

print(sum)
```

Comment: That worked. I'll try to integrate this into function and i will see.

Comment: Code works as intended, but if i integrate it in a function and write something like that "function(101011000111010001100100110101011001011000110111001)", then it returns different number. Is her any way to automatically convert input into string?

Comment: 101011000111010001100100110101011001011000110111001
How should your computer know that this is supposed to be a binary number?
The maximum number native Lua 5.3 can handle is 9223372036854775807 which as you can see is much smaller than the number you try to process.
Please make yourself familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow

If you don't want to process a string you can work with an array of ones and zeroes

Comment: I was thinking about doing this trough array, but i have no idea how to separate string by symbols. For example "abc" to "a","b","c".

Comment: the simplest approach would be lhf's answer. But it only works if you have the binary number as a string. you can get parts of a string by string.sub(), see Lua reference.

Answer (score 11):

In Lua 5.3, `tonumber` works just fine:

```
Lua 5.3.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> tonumber("1000100110100011111010101001001001001100100101",2)
37834277032741
> tonumber("10010011001100011001011110001100000110110101100",2)
80920602611116
```

Comment: lua 5.1.5 also support this. //not sure other version

Comment: offical docs, seems 5.0,4.0,3.0 already has `tonumber()`:  
https://www.lua.org/manual/3.0/manual.html#tonumber  
https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#tonumber  
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html

Comment: @yurenchen, yes, but it doesn’t mean 64-bits are supported

Comment: tested on lua5.1.5 (the oldest lua version which I have): result same as yours 
(maybe that mean 64-bits supported

Comment: @yurenchen, in Lua 5.2-, there was only one type of number, represented by default by double-precisions floats. The numbers above do not fit into 32 bits but do fit into the 52 bits that doubles have. Lua 5.3 introduced support for integers, 64-bit by default.